# RegExp: Find out the name and state from a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to find the names from the following string

"pluto,standing saturn3os,standing marsplanet,standing jupiter_21,walking"

The regexp I am using is 
var myName = /[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+,/im;

But it searches only "pluto,".

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below could will work fine using split function,

```
var value = "pluto,standing saturn3os,standing marsplanet,standing jupiter_21,walking";
value = value.split( ",");
console.log(value);
```

Comment: Note that this solution assumes that the input will always be a list of things delimited by string and also assumes that you don't have to drill into the tokenized list to get what you want from each substring

Answer (score 0):

Should add 'g', and `\s` to your RegExp.

```
"pluto,standing saturn3os,standing marsplanet,standing jupiter_21,walking".match(/[a-zA-Z0-9._-\s]+/g)
```

Or in this particular case you can use `split(',')`.

Happy Coding!!

Comment: should add space (no pun indented haha) in the character range right? and drop the coma (you did it but did not explain that)

Comment: Yes, so the expression should be like this `/[a-zA-Z0-9._-\s]+/g`. Or you can just `split(',')`

Comment: yeah! you should propose the split solution in your answer, less expensive, and edit the solution to include \s